# Does the Well Stocked improvement apply when flipping over infection cards (from the top of the deck) or just when drawing them (from the bottom)?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

The *Well Stocked* infection card improvement says

> If there are 2 or more supply cubes on this city when this card is drawn, do not remove any supply cubes.

[That question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/41773/), and [two](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1891050/) [threads](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1880728/) on BGG, wonder whether this applies when an infection card is drawn from the bottom of the deck. It is clear to me that it does. But, I wonder about the complement: does the effect also triggers when flipping over infection cards from the *top* of the deck?

Let me explain. It seems equally reasonable to me to read the card as applying *only* when drawing infection cards from the *bottom* of the deck. The reason is that, when referring to infection cards, the rules very systematically use the term “flip over” for “picking an infection card from the top of the deck”. (It is used in such a way in the rules about the setup, step 4 and about the Infect step of a normal player turn.) Whereas it uses systematically the term “draw”, when referring to infection cards, to mean “picking an infection card from the bottom of the deck”. (It is used in such a way in the details about the Infect step of resolving an epidemic card.) (The term is also used in other contexts with the usual meaning, such as, pick a card from the top of the legacy deck or the player deck.) And, remarkably, the translation in French also uses distinct words in exactly the same circumstances, so this choice of word seems to be on purpose.

The rules do mention that “Infection improvements are in effect during (…) The Infect step at the end of every player turn”, but I have some doubts that it answers my question. If we are supposed to consider that flipping over (thus, picking from the top) is not drawing (thus, picking from the bottom), then the improvement may well be “in effect” during the Infect step at the end of my turn, but the effect will boil down to doing nothing, as the effect happens only when drawing (thus, picking from the bottom).

I hope that my question is clear and that some official clarification can be brought.

Answer (score 2):

The well stocked improvement applies whenever you draw the card. The answer is in the links you provided so maybe you're having a harder time with the translation, but the key part is

> Infection improvements are in effect during:
>
> - Game set up
> - The Infect step during an Epidemic
> - **The Infect step at the end of every player turn**

The **Infect step at the end of every player** turn is when you are drawing cards from the top of the deck, and the well stocked improvement applies during part as well, per the rule above.

The **Infect step during an Epidemic** is specifically when you draw from the bottom of the deck.